# Can't put created paragraph element into div?

Tags: javascript

So i'm trying to make a simple comments page but I can't seem to get it working :/ Is there something wrong with the code? I'm trying to use only javascript since I have not learned JQuery

```
function action(){

    var input = document.getElementById('header').value;
    localStorage.setItem('comment',input);
    document.getElementById('header').value=" ";
    var getInput = localStorage.getItem('comment');
    var date = Date();
    var parag = document.createElement('P')
    parag.innerText=getInput;
    document.getElementById('hello').appendChild=parag;

 }
 <textarea id='header' type='text' rows='6' cols='100' name='server'>
 </textarea>
 <input onclick="action();" type="button" value='Comment'>
 <span id='hello'></span>
```

Comment: Maybe obvious but … You *do* realise that the Javascript code needs to be wrapped in a `<script>` tag, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('hello').appendChild=parag;
```

You are not calling the appendChild function properly. You are assigning instead. You should do

```
 document.getElementById('hello').appendChild(parag);
```

Note: in below codes I removed the local storage because of security issues.

--

```js
function action(){

    var input = document.getElementById('header').value;
    //localStorage.setItem('comment',input);
    document.getElementById('header').value=" ";
   // var getInput = localStorage.getItem('comment');
    var date = Date();
    var parag = document.createElement('P')
    parag.innerText="getInput";
    document.getElementById('hello').appendChild(parag);

 }
```

```html
 <textarea id='header' type='text' rows='6' cols='100' name='server'>
 </textarea>
 <input onclick="action();" type="button" value='Comment'>
 <span id='hello'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change you append child to :

```
document.getElementById('hello').appendChild(parag);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function action(){
    var input = document.getElementById('header').value;
    localStorage.setItem('comment',input);
    document.getElementById('header').value=" ";
    var getInput = localStorage.getItem('comment');
    var parag = document.createElement('P')
    parag.innerText=getInput;
    document.getElementById('hello').appendChild(parag);

 }

</script>
  <body>
 <textarea id='header' type='text' rows='6' cols='100' name='server'>
 </textarea>
 <input onclick="action();" type="button" value='Comment'>
 <div id='hello'></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `Node.appendChild` is wrong.

You can see how to use it in the [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-appendchild).

> The appendChild(node) method, when invoked, must return the result of appending node to context object.

You should also consider keeping a reference to header instead of querying the DOM twice.